# Economizing on variable use

Tags: c

I am working on some (embedded) device, recently I just started thinking maybe to use less memory, in case stack size isn't that big.
I have long functions (unfortunately).
And inside I was thinking to save space in this way.
Imagine there is code

```
1. void f()
2. {
3. ...
4. char someArray[300];
5. char someOtherArray[300];
6. someFunc(someArray, someOtherArray);
7. ...
8. }
```

Now, imagine, `someArray` and `someOtherArray` are never used in `f` function **beyond** line: 6.
Would following save some stack space??

```
1. void f()
2. {
3. ...
4. {//added
5. char someArray[300];
6. char someOtherArray[300];
7. someFunc(someArray, someOtherArray);
8. }//added
9. ...
8. }
```

*nb*: removed second part of the question

Comment: I don't think there's difference.  The *preprocessor* will replace the macros before the compiler get the code.

Comment: @maroun maroun: My reasoning was that with MACRO case, it will consume less space. Because memory will be allocated for it ONCE, and then it can be used in many places like I showed in my code. Whereas with directly injecting string literals in code, I thought each time new space would be allocated for it -- I was wrong?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure, I prefer someone else answer this. I don't want to mislead you.

Comment: @dmcr_code There is no difference, both are equal. Using the macro will result in literals after the preprocessing phase.

Comment: But it is irrelevant anyway. Any half-decent compiler will notice that literals are same, and reserve memory to only once. So you will not save any memory that way.

Comment: Maroun is right. The compilter cant tell the difference between the two codes. The text it will receive will be identical in both cases.

Comment: As for using the extra scope: any C compiler should be able to that, unless you try to use those variables after the scope ends.

Comment: @user694733 And in this case, the claim that it won't be used after line 6 is wrong.

Comment: @glglgl Whoops, I missed the part :P

Comment: And the compiler should optimize it, so that identical strings are only placed once in your executable either way.

Comment: @user694733: please check my modified question on what happens when I add: {}

Comment: @dmcr_code Which line is 230?

Comment: @user694733: Sorry, yes you were right I was closing the scope at the wrong space. But now, can you answer if using {} saves space or not? (after I managed to compile it)?

Comment: @dmcr_code It depends on the compiler. See glglgl's answer.

Comment: Please, please don't ask two questions in one. I'd strongly suggest that you open a second one for the string literal question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern compilers should push stack variables before they are used, and pop them when they are no longer needed. The old thinking with `{ ... }` marking the start and end of a stack push/pop should be rather obsolete by now.

Since 1999, C allows stack variables to be allocated anywhere and not just immediately after a `{`. C++ allowed this far earlier. Today, where the local variable is declared inside the scope has little to do with when it actually starts to exist in the machine code. And similarly, the `}` has little to do with when is ceases to exist.

So regarding adding extra `{ }`, don't bother. It is premature optimization and only adds pointless clutter.

---

Regarding the `#define` it absolutely makes no difference in terms of efficiency. Macros are just text replacement.

---

Furthermore, from the generic point-of-view, *data must always be allocated somewhere*. Data used by a program cannot be allocated in thin air! That's a very common misunderstanding. For example, many people incorrectly believe that

```
int x = func();
if(x == something)
```

consumes more memory than

```
if(func() == something)
```

But both examples compile into identical machine code. The result of `func` must be stored *somewhere*, it cannot be stored in thin air. In the first example, the result is stored in a memory segment that the programmer may refer to as `x`.

In the second example, it is stored in the very same memory segment, taking up the same amount of space, for the same duration of program execution. The only difference is that the memory segment is anonymous and the programmer has no name for it. As far as the machine code is concerned, that doesn't matter, since no variable names exist in machine code.

And this would be why every professional C programmer needs to understand a certain amount of assembler. You cannot hope to ever do any kind of manual code optimization if you don't.

Answer (score 3):

For the compiler proper both are exactly the same and thus makes no difference. The preprocessor would replace all instances of `TEXT1` with the string constant.

```
#define TEXT1 "SomeLongStringLiteral"
someFunc(TEXT1)
someOtherFunc(TEXT1)
```

After the preprocessor's job is done, the above snippet becomes

```
someFunc("SomeLongStringLiteral");
someOtherFunc("SomeLongStringLiteral");
```

Thus it makes no difference performance or memory-wise.

**Aside:** The reason `#define TEXT1 "SomeLongStringLiteral"` is done is to have a single place to change all instances of `TEXT1`s usage; but that's a convinience only for the programmer and has no effect on the produced output.

> recently I just started thinking maybe to use less memory, in case stack size isn't that big.

Never micro optimise or prematurely optimise. *In case the stack size isn't that big*, you'll get to know it when you benchmark/measure it. Don't make any assumptions when you optimise; 99% of the times it'd be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> I am working on some device

Really? Are you? I wouldn't have thought that.

> Now, imagine, `someArray` and `someOtherArray` are never used in `f` function beyond line 6. Would following save some stack space?

On a good compiler, it wouldn't make a difference. By the standard, it isn't specified if it saves or not, it isn't even specified if there is a stack or not.

But on a not so good compiler, the one with the additional `{}` may be better. It is worth a test: compile it and look at the generated assembler code.

> it seems my compiler doesn't allow me to do this (this is C), so never mind...

But it should so. What happens then? Maybe you are just confusing levels of `{}` ...

> I'll ask another one here.

Would better be a separate question...

```
someFunc("SomeLongStringLiteral");
someOtherFunc("SomeLongStringLiteral");
```

vs.

```
someFunc(TEXT1)
someOtherFunc(TEXT1)
```

A `#define` is processed before any compilation step, so it makes absolutely no difference.

If it happens within the same compilation unit, the compiler will tie them together anyway. (At least, in this case. On an ATXmega, if you use `PSTR("whatever")` for having them in flash space only, each occurrence of them will be put into flash separately. But that's a completely different thing...)

Comment: please see my modified question about error I get when I added scope symbols: {}.

Comment: hmm I compiled it. So now just interested if using scope symbols, space is saved ..

Comment: @dmcr_code Obviously, you use one of the arrays *after* your scope. So maybe put one inside (the bigger one?) and the other one outside.

Comment: the point was I was using one of the arrays Outside the scope. I am not that "experienced" at looking assembly codes... :(( etc. is there no standard answer to this? the variable should die after the scope right?

Comment: @dmcr_code Normally, yes. But it may depend on the compiler, the target architecture and the compiler options. There is no standard answer for this.

Comment: ok but I am not sure how to look at assembly code ... (so I'd just give it a try if I need space etc.)

Comment: @dmcr_code Depends on your compiler as well. YOu s hould look at its documentation.

Comment: by device initially I meant embedded device. I'm not sure there will be some nice doc about it. Anyway, this won't spoil anything right?

Comment: The concept of only having string literals allocated once is commonly called "string pooling" or [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). There is usually a compiler optimizer option called string pooling or similar.

Comment: On an AT Mega, why on earth would you want string literals to be allocated anywhere but in flash?

Comment: @Lundin Both approaches have their downsides. If I keep them only in flash, I have to use other access methods to retrieve them (`lpm` and friends). If I have them copied to RAM at init time, it eats up my RAM. The default method is the latter one, if you use the former one, you'll have to use e.g. `strcpy_P()` instead of `strcpy()`.

Comment: @glglgl Obviously if you want to alter them, they would have to be copied to RAM at some point. If you don't, there should be no reason why they can't reside in flash. I don't know about Atmel, but other (modern) architectures can access flash constants just fine without using special functions.

Comment: @Lundin ATXmega is Harvard architecture and thus has RAM and flash in separate address spaces. That makes it so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

(Please don't ask two questions in one, this is really annoying since you get two types of answer for your two different questions.)

For your first question. Probably putting `{}` around the use of a variable will not help. The lifetime of automatic variables that are not VLA (see below) is *not* bound to the scope in which it is declared. So compilers may have a hard time in figuring out how the use of the stack may be optimized, and maybe don't do such an optimization at all. In your case this is most likely the case, since you are exporting pointers to your data to a function that is perhaps not visible, here. The compiler has no way to figure out if there is a valid use of the arrays later on in the code.

I see two ways to "force" the compiler into optimizing that space, functions or VLA. The first, functions is simple: instead of putting the block around the code, put it in a `static` function. Function calls are quite optimized on modern platforms, and here the compiler knows exactly how he may clear the stack at the end.

The second alternative in your case is a VLA, variable length array, if you compiler supports that c99 feature. Arrays that have a size that doesn't depend on a compile time constant have a special rule for their lifetime. That lifetime exactly ends at the end of the scope where they are defined. Even a `const`-qualified variable could be used for that:

```
{
  size_t const len = 300;
  char someArray[len];
  char someOtherArray[len];
  someFunc(someArray, someOtherArray);
}
```

At the end, on a given platform, you'd really have to inspect what assembler your compiler produces.